# Detect if array has only null values in it

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I would like a simple non-loop test if that arrays contains ONLY `null` values. Empty array also counts as having only null values.

I guess another way to describe the issue is to test if the array has at least one non-null value.

So:

```
Good: [ null, null, null ]
Good: []
Bad:  [ null, 3, null ]
```

Comment: Why don't you simply loop and test all values ?

Comment: Very large and called very often. Might map it to a mongodb db in the future.

Comment: `!arr.some(function(v) { return v !== null; });` ... but of course that loops at some level. You cannot compare values in an array without looping.

Comment: @FelixKling ty, post it as an answer pls

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031690/check-if-an-array-contains-something-other-than-null-in-javascript

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is a simple:

```
Array.prototype.isNull = function (){
    return this.join().replace(/,/g,'').length === 0;
};

[null, null, null].isNull(); // true
[null, 3, null].isNull(); // false
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ANxbe/).

This takes the array, joins the elements of that array together (without arguments `join()` joins the array elements together with `,` characters) to return a string, replaces all the `,` characters in that string (using a regular expression) with empty strings and then tests if the length is equal to `0`. So:

```
[null, 3, null].isNull()
```

Joined together to give:

```
',3,'
```

Has all the commas replaced (using the `g` flag after the regular expression), to give:

```
'3'
```

Tested to see if its length is equal to `0`, to give:

```
false
```

It's worth noting that there is the problem of, potentially, the `,` featuring in the checked arrays.

Also, [Felix Kling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337820/82548) *is* [somewhat faster](http://jsperf.com/so-q-19337761).

Comment: Beat me to it. Just hope there are no commas in the array

Comment: Er... isn't it a bad practice to modify the prototype of built-in types? No offense :)

Comment: It has a bad rep in some situations, but honestly? So far it's never caused me a problem, which is (definitively) *not* any kind of proof of its safety.

Comment: @David Thomas, can you please explain to me what `replace(/,/g,'')` is doing? specially `/,/g` part.

Comment: it seeks for the `,` character where as the `g` character specifies to search for ALL (global) instances, not just the first one. So it replaces all instances of `,` with '' which is nothing.

Comment: @th1rdey3: sorry, I edited the explanation into the answer, and forgot to notify you. Oops.

Comment: Some junior uses `for-in` to iterate over array and all of the sudden new enumerable `isNull` property comes up.

Comment: @Pavlo: I'm aware of the problem, but thank you for taking the time to explain it to those that *aren't*; it's just that it's never, as I said, caused *me* a problem. Possibly because I've never been in a situation where I've needed to iterate, with a `for-in`, over an array.

Comment: well, `[",,"]` and similar...

Comment: @Pavlo: That junior will have then learned a lesson that day, and improved their understanding and skill. Certainly you don't consider that a bad thing, right?

Comment: @DavidThomas My solution is faster now :) http://jsperf.com/so-q-19337761/3

Comment: It's disappointing that experienced developer proposes a solution that: a) has an obvious flaw (`[','].isNull() === true`), b) needlessly complicated, c) widely considered as bad practice. Now it's even accepted. I wish I could downvote more.

Comment: Who's an 'experienced developer'? I'm purely a hobbyist (though I'm *usually* still reasonably good ).

Comment: @Pavlo: *what* is widely considered bad practice? Extending `Array.prototype`? If so, that's nonsense. It may be bad practice when designing a publicly used code library *(at least without clear documentation of the fact)*, but beyond that, it's neither good nor bad. It's just one approach to a problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas The only metrics I could rely upon is SO rep, and you have a lot more than OP. And no matter of your professional occupation, you are responsible for the answers you are giving.

Comment: @Pavlo: of course I am, my point wasn't to abdicate, or otherwise forsake, my 'responsibility' (such as it is), it's that your criteria for judgement was flawed.

Comment: @user2736012 I'm not going to expand this discussion here, because except this point the answer has two much more important downsides that I've mentioned earlier.

Comment: While it looks pretty, behind th scenes its doing much more work than a simple loop and has a loop anhways internally somewhere inside the join.

Comment: Late comment, but you can get around the comma issue by sending an empty string as a delimiter.  So `[1,2,3].join()` produces `"1,2,3"` but `[1,2,3].join('')` produces `"123"`.

Answer (score 28):

You can avoid using an *explicit* loop by using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var all_null = arr.every(function(v) { return v === null; });
```

but of course internally the engine will still iterate over the array.  Iterating over the array explicitly might actually be faster. The important thing to do is *break* out of the loop once you encounter an element which is not `null` (the method does that).

This method is not supported in every browser, see the link for a polyfill.

Comment: +1 Or, with underscore.js: `var all_null = !_.some(arr);`

Comment: @kol: Changed to `every` (easier to understand and works the same) but yes!

Comment: +1 for a safer, and approx 1500 ops/sec faster, solution. :)

Comment: I added the underscore version to the jsperf page: http://jsperf.com/so-q-19337761/2

Comment: @David: Interestingly, in FF your solution seems to be faster :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: of course not! :) And, Felix: excellent! I don't feel so bad about it, now... ;)

Comment: ES6 syntax: `const all_null = arr.every( ( v ) => v === null )`

Answer (score 5):

```
var arrayData1 = [null, null, null];
var arrayData2 = [];
var arrayData3 = [null, 3, null];
var arrayData4 = [3];

function isNull(inputArray) {
    if (inputArray.length) {
        var currentElement = inputArray[0];
        for (var i = 1, len = inputArray.length; i < len && currentElement === null; i += 1) {
            currentElement = currentElement || inputArray[i];
        }
        if (currentElement !== null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isNull(arrayData1));
console.log(isNull(arrayData2));
console.log(isNull(arrayData3));
console.log(isNull(arrayData4));
```

**Output**

```
true
true
false
false
```

**Edit 1:** And here comes the most efficient solution (suggested by user2736012). This solution applies **KISS** principle. **K** eep **I** t **S** imple, **S** illy.

```
function isNull(inputArray) {
  for (var i = 0, len = inputArray.length; i < len; i += 1)
    if (inputArray[i] !== null)
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Performance Result: http://jsperf.com/so-q-19337761/6

Comment: Your `for` loop is strange, and as a result `isNull()` returns `true` for `[3]` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQeaq/)).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I fixed it now. Please check. :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks to you. After the modifications, my solution is little faster than the other solutions (atleast on my browser) http://jsperf.com/so-q-19337761/3

Comment: Indeed, on my Firefox 23 it is 0.40% faster than even `!_.some()` (which I imagine was implemented the same way :)

Comment: There's much more complexity there than is needed. You can simplify with just a `for` and `if` statement. http://jsfiddle.net/wG9sR/

Comment: @user2736012 Hands down. It beats all the other solution suggested in performance. http://jsperf.com/so-q-19337761/6

Comment: @user2736012 Updated my answer with the latest jsperf results

Comment: So, in the end, the simple loop beats both regex matching and function mapping. **Long live the simple loop.**

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Indeed. Updated my answer with KISS principle... :P