# Check if an array contains something other than null in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array that will most likely always look like:

```
[null, null, null, null, null]
```

sometimes this array might change to something like:

```
["helloworld", null, null, null, null]
```

I know I could use a for loop for this but is there a way to use `indexOf` to check if something in an array that is not equal to null.

I am looking for something like:

```
var index = indexof(!null);
```

Comment: Why should you even have an array of null elements? There's no way to do it without iterating (or recursively searching), unless you have an nonderministic machine that guesses always the correct answer, yes or no.

Comment: Well I'm making a website where you can select out of 5 league of legends champs and if they don't select a champ then the array will stay at null. I tried the for loop method but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which returns a boolean:

```js
const arr = [null, 2, null, null];
const arr2 = [null, null, null, null];

function otherThanNull(arr) {
  return arr.some(el => el !== null);
}

console.log(otherThanNull(arr));
console.log(otherThanNull(arr2));
```

Answer (score 4):

In recent versions of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox (and future versions of other browsers), you can use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill) to find the index of the first non-null element.

```js
var arr = [null, null, "not null", null];

var first = arr.findIndex( 
              function(el) { 
                return (el !== null);
              }
            );

console.log(first);
```

(for other browsers, there's a [polyfill for `findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill))

Comment: Note, *none* of the IE browsers support `findIndex`, not just "older" browsers (IE 11 is still considered "new").

Comment: @TbWill4321 True. But the polyfill works fine there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.some` to check if there are any elements matching a function:

```js
var array = [null, null, 2, null];
var hasValue = array.some(function(value) {
    return value !== null;
});
document.write('Has Value? ' + hasValue);
```

If you want the first index of a non-null element, you'll have to get a bit trickier.  First, map each element to true / false, then get the indexOf true:

```js
var array = [null, null, 2, null, 3];
var index = array
    .map(function(value) { return value !== null })
    .indexOf(true);
document.write('Non-Null Index Is: ' + index);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just wanna check if there is any non-[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value in the array, do

```
arr.some(el => !!el)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the work

```
var array = ['hello',null,null];
var array2 = [null,null,null];

$.each(array, function(i, v){ 
    if(!(v == null)) alert('Contains data');
})
```